# Neo4j.rb default integer value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j.rb

i've a problem with finding all the nodes that are invalids.
here's the class :

```
class MyNode
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  property :name
  property :is_valid, type: Integer, default: 0
end
```

When my nodes are created the property is not set automatically apparently. Then i want to search all the nodes that are invalids and it returns 0

```
classobject.as(:n).where(is_valid: [0,'']).count
```

i've tried with that as well

```
validates :is_valid, numericality: { only_integer: true }
```

how should i handle this ?

Comment: `MyNode.where(is_valid: 0).count` what it returns?

Comment: same thing. but if i update a node already created to set is_valid=0 then it returns it

Comment: First you create `MyNode.create(name: 'aa', is_valid: 0)` Then `MyNode.reload!` and then `MyNode.where(is_valid: 0).count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my problem by systematically adding is_valid: 0 to my parameters where it was created. i was thinking that as it has been set as default: 0 it would be automatically set